# How to join list of strings at specific indices only

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I'm trying to join specific strings in a list of strings together at specific indices only in Python. Imagine you have the list

`['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux']`

I would want to end up with, for example, the following list:

`['foo', 'bar baz', 'qux', 'quux']`

Given that the list of strings contains the string `baz`.

What would be the most efficient way of going about this?

Comment: Do you have your own non-efficient method to show us?

Comment: What happens if `baz` is the first element?

Comment: In my situation that's not possible with the data I'm working with, but that's a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
index = 2
ss = ['foo','bar','far','car','sar']
ss[index] = ' '.join(ss[index:index+2])
ss.pop(index+1)
print(ss)
```

I hope this works , as it doesn't require new list to be created

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise I could simply use the `pop` function to get rid of the duplicate element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux']
>>> index = 2
>>> l[index - 1] = f'{l[index-1]} {l.pop(index)}'
>>> l
['foo', 'bar baz', 'qux', 'quux']
```

Timing:

```
382 ns ± 0.455 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    print(s[i])
    if s[i] == 'baz' and i != 0:
        s[i - 1] += ' '
        s[i - 1] += ''.join(s[i])
        s.pop(i)
        i = i - 1
    i = i + 1
```

The above code traverses the list, and wherever 'baz' is found, it concatenates 'baz' to the preceding element. This cannot be achieved using for loop, by `for i in s` or `for i in range(len(s))`. In the code, since len(s) is changing because of s.pop(), `i = i - 1` was necessary, but `for i in range(len(s))` doesn't allow to change the value of i, as it is fixed to go from 0 to len(s). For any doubt regarding why not use for loop, consider the following code :-

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
    if s[i] == 'baz':
        s.pop(i)
    i = i - 1
```

This outputs

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-223-8034ffc6ca03> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(s)):
----> 2     print(s[i])
      3     if s[i] == 'baz':
      4         s.pop(i)
      5     i = i - 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

As can be seen, it does not traverse all the elements. Because of s.pop(), len(s) got reduced to 4, and s[3] became 'quux', and not 'qux'. Inspite of i being `i - 1`, it throws an error. Hence while loop solves the problem.